# Quarkus test fails after adding qute dependency

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, quarkus-qute

I was working on a Quarkus AWS lambda service that generates some html reports and uploads to S3. After implementation, I found that my lambda tests started failing with 404.

Analysing further, I found that the quarkus-resteasy-qute dependency that I added was the culprit. As soon as I add this dependency to my project, my lambda handler test case starts failing with a 404. My plan was to use qute for some templating of the reports generated by the lambda.

I have replicated the same in a starter project [here](https://github.com/faskan/quarkus-lambda-qute/). I don't have any clue on what exactly in this dependency is causing the failure.

Really appreciate any help or pointers to debug it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quarkus-resteasy-qute` will **NOT** work with regular lambda. It would work with `quarkus-amazon-lambda-http` (or rest) which spins up an API gateway on AWS though.

Reference: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24312